# How Can I Update this Array in my Collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection of users, and inside each user I have an array that I want to target

I have this endpoint in my routes that is successfully retrieving my user from the db:

```
 async addHabitToUser(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.headers

    const user = await User.findById(user_id)

    console.log(user)
  }
```

However, I'm having trouble updating it. All of the examples I've seen instantiate the db before updating, but since I have my connection setup in server.js I'm not sure how to access the update methods.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Mongoose to get and update your data from mongoDB you can use `save`:

```
const user = await User.findById(user_id)
user.age = 20;
await user.save();
```

This will take the changes and save them to the mongoDB

If you want to do it directly you can also use:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

```
const doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: 'John Doe' },
  { title: 'Missing' },
  // If `new` isn't true, `findOneAndUpdate()` will return the
  // document as it was _before_ it was updated.
  { new: true }
);

doc.title; // Should be equal "Missing"
```

You can read more about each on: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update